# quantity field increase in arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

I need to increase the value of the quantity field, if the customer selects the same product to add items to the arraylist.

I have a link `addtoitems`, when customer click on this link, product_id,user_id,product_name,price will send to the `addtocart` method.

In that `addtocart` method I created a list which is session based, added items that is `product_id, user_id, product_name, price, quantity` and some integer value `i=0` to the arraylist.

My problem is, if the user select the same item in the product table, the arraylist quantity field should increase.

But here I am getting the problem that every request that comes from the customer (I mean on the same item), is increasing the quantity field but it is adding one more item(product_id,user_id,product_name,price,quantity,and some integer value i=0) to the arraylist.

```
// adding addtocart details to shopping cart table  arraylist
@RequestMapping(value = "/addtocart", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView addToCart(ModelAndView model, HttpServletRequest req,
        HttpServletResponse res,
        HttpSession session,
        @RequestParam Integer product_id,
        @RequestParam String price,
        @RequestParam String product_name,
        @RequestParam Integer user_id,
        @ModelAttribute Product product) {

    req.getSession().setAttribute("product_id", product_id);

    //adding multiple products to the list starts here
    session = req.getSession();
    // here session.setAttribute list value stored in 
    session.getAttribute("list");
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    List<Shopping_Cart> list = (List<Shopping_Cart>) session.getAttribute("list");

    if (list == null) {
        list = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    int i = 1;
    int quantity = 0;
    // Add the product_id,user_id,product_name & price to List
    list.add(new Shopping_Cart(product_id, user_id, product_name, price, i, quantity));

    int prod_id = 0;

    for (Shopping_Cart qnty : list) {
        prod_id = qnty.getProduct_id();

        if (prod_id == product_id) {
            qnty.setQuantity(qnty.getQuantity() + 1);
        } else {

        }
    }

    session.setAttribute("list", list);
    return new ModelAndView("ViewAddToCart");
}
```

Comment: this question needs some editing

Answer (score 0):

First:
If you want to increase a value inside a list, you can do this short and quickly with a stream:

```
list.stream().filter(p -> p.getProductId().equals(productId)).map(p -> p.setQuantity(p.getQuantity() + 1));
```

Second:
As you recognized, you cannot identify a product only by its ID, so you need a kind of tuple (productId, userSession).
Try to assign a session to each user and do the following:

```
list.stream().filter(user -> user.getSessionId().equals(sessionIdOfRequestingUser).filter(p -> p.getProductId().equals(productIdThatWasAdded)).map(p -> p.addQuantity(1));
```

Then I would give the class Product a method that allows to increase the quantity. If this method accepts a value, you can easily do some quickselect stuff later:

```
public void addQuantity(int quantity) {
  this.quantity += quantity;
}
```

Update:
Just saw that you are passing a userId, so you can do:

```
list.stream().filter(user -> user.getSessionId().equals(userId).filter(p -> p.getProductId().equals(productIdThatWasAdded)).map(p -> p.addQuantity(1));
```